# How to catch stderr inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, stderr

I've built a docker image named `conda` with several dependencies. And I've written a  node.js script to launch a container of this image. However, I cannot catch exceptions that I raise inside the container. Here's my node.js demo `test.js`:

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');

child_process.exec(`docker run --rm -t -v "$PWD:/env" --entrypoint python conda test.py`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (stdout) console.log('stdout: ', stdout);
    if (stderr) console.log('stderr: ', stderr);
})
```

where the `test.py` is simply:

```py
import sys

raise ValueError('this is a value error')
```

When I run `node test.js` from terminal, the output is:

```
stdout:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    raise ValueError('this is a value error')
ValueError: this is a value error
```

Which shows that a raised exception is caught as stdout inside the docker container. However if I change my js file to:

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');

child_process.exec(`python test.py`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (stdout) console.log('stdout: ', stdout);
    if (stderr) console.log('stderr: ', stderr);
})
```

Then the output is logged as expected:

```
stderr:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vector/playgournd/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    raise ValueError('this is a value error')
ValueError: this is a value error
```

From my point of view there must be some tricks with stream piping inside docker. Anyone can help?

Comment: **It's the `-t`.** Because you use `docker run -t` both stdout and stderr inside the container are mapped to the (one, single) pty, and all output via that pty comes out to the host's stdout. If you want to do something in a container where the difference between stdout and stderr matters, don't use `-t`. (You'd get the same effect with other things that run a child 'behind' a pty like `expect` and optionally `ssh`.)